# Linq Count() will always return 1 within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

**Background**

Right now I have a system named FoorBar where there are Users, Rooms, and Authorizations.

**Detailed Background**

A user can have many authorizations and many rooms can be added to a single authorization. To handle this I have the following tables: `FooBar_User`, `FooBar_UserAuth`, `FooBar_Authorization`, `FoorBar_AuthType`, `FooBar_RoomAuth`, and `Room_Inventory`.

I need a query to return the authorization id, the number of rooms a user has, the authorization type, and the expiration date of the authorization.

**SQL**

The SQL to generate the desired output is below:

```
SELECT a.AuthId
    ,COUNT(ra.RoomAuthId) AS RmCnt
    ,fat.AuthTypeAbbr
    ,a.ExpirationDate

FROM FooBar_User AS u
    INNER JOIN FooBar_UserAuth AS ua ON u.UserId = ua.UserId
    INNER JOIN FooBar_Authorization AS a ON ua.AuthId = a.AuthId
    INNER JOIN FooBar_AuthType AS fat ON a.AuthTypeId = fat.AuthTypeId
    LEFT JOIN FooBar_RoomAuth AS ra ON a.AuthId = ra.AuthId AND ra.IsActive = 1
    LEFT JOIN Room_Inventory AS ri ON ra.RmId = ri.RMID AND ri.IsActive = 1

WHERE   a.IsActive =  1
    AND u.IsActive =  1
    AND u.UserId   = 10

GROUP BY a.AuthId, fat.AuthTypeAbbr, a.ExpirationDate
```

**LINQ Query**

```
from ua in db.FooBar_UserAuth
join ra in db.FooBar_RoomAuth
    on new { ua.FooBar_Authorization.AuthId, IsActive = true }
    equals new { ra.AuthId, ra.IsActive } into raJoin
from ra in raJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join ri in db.Room_Inventory
    on new { ra.RmId, IsActive = true }
    equals new { RmId = ri.RMID, ri.IsActive } into riJoin
from ri in riJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
    ua.FooBar_Authorization.IsActive &&
    ua.IsPi == true &&
    ua.FooBar_User.IsActive &&
    ua.FooBar_User.UserId == 10
group new { ua.FooBar_Authorization, ua.FooBar_Authorization.FooBar_AuthType, ra } by new
{
    AuthId = (int?)ua.FooBar_Authorization.AuthId,
    ua.FooBar_Authorization.FooBar_AuthType.AuthTypeAbbr,
    ua.FooBar_Authorization.ExpirationDate
} into g
select new
{
    AuthId = g.Key.AuthId.Value,
    RmCnt = g.Count(p => p.ra.RoomAuthId != 0),
    AuthType = g.Key.AuthTypeAbbr,
    ExpirationDate = g.Key.ExpirationDate
}
```

**LINQPad and Linqer Output**

```
AuthId  RmCnt   AuthType    ExpirationDate
30      0       Type1       12/31/2020
31      0       Type2       12/31/2020
```

**Problem**

The issue is that this LINQ query works perfectly when it is run in both Linqer and LINQPad. The output is exactly as desired. However, when it is run in C# with ASP.NET, MVC, and Entity Framework, the RmCnt will never be `0`. Instead, it will be `1`. No matter what is changed that seems to be the case. One other user asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791614/) but I can't figure out how to apply their solution with my query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the output of the query is 1 and that is not an output Status Code from the code execution?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have checked it both by printing it to the actual page as well as looking through the results in debug mode of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem

**Problem**

I am still not sure what the root cause of the problem is as the LINQ Query I had originally worked perfectly in LINQPad and Linqer but not in the actual code.

However, one of the things I changed from the original output of Linqer was changing `p.ra.AuthTypeId != null` to `p.ra.AuthTypeId != 0` because Visual Studio was complaining that `AuthTypeId` can never be null as it is an `int` rather than a `Nullable<int>`.

**Solution**

It was actually a rather simple change. `p.ra.AuthTypeId != 0` needed to be changed to `p.ra != null`. This solution makes Visual Studio not complain about nullable types but still maintains the same output.

**Full Working LINQ Query**

```
from ua in db.FooBar_UserAuth
join ra in db.FooBar_RoomAuth
    on new { ua.FooBar_Authorization.AuthId, IsActive = true }
    equals new { ra.AuthId, ra.IsActive } into raJoin
from ra in raJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join ri in db.Room_Inventory
    on new { ra.RmId, IsActive = true }
    equals new { RmId = ri.RMID, ri.IsActive } into riJoin
from ri in riJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
    ua.FooBar_Authorization.IsActive &&
    ua.IsPi == true &&
    ua.FooBar_User.IsActive &&
    ua.FooBar_User.UserId == 10
group new { ua.FooBar_Authorization, ua.FooBar_Authorization.FooBar_AuthType, ra } by new
{
    AuthId = (int?)ua.FooBar_Authorization.AuthId,
    ua.FooBar_Authorization.FooBar_AuthType.AuthTypeAbbr,
    ua.FooBar_Authorization.ExpirationDate
} into g
select new
{
    AuthId = g.Key.AuthId.Value,
    RmCnt = g.Count(p => p.ra != null),
    AuthType = g.Key.AuthTypeAbbr,
    ExpirationDate = g.Key.ExpirationDate
}
```